# If possible can you host a .Net core web API from it's solution/project folder and debug though IIS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, .net-core, hosting

I am wondering if it is possible to run a .net core Web API application from its solution/project folder in IIS.

Currently, I can do this with standard .net and IIS and it works great but I've had no luck doing this .net core or able to find any information regarding this.

I have been successful in publishing and hosting the API, I imagine I can debug using that method? but may not be ideal. (just tested this with no luck but will continue to follow up)

(I'm fairly new .net core as I've inherited a .net core API)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, if you're going down vote can I get a comment or reason?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/07/13/development-time-iis-support-for-asp-net-core-applications/ Clearly it is supported but requires extra setup.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks, I wasn't sure and none of my searches seemed to come up with anything relevant. I Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/07/13/development-time-iis-support-for-asp-net-core-applications/

Thanks, Lexi, just what I was looking for.

I hope this helps someone else with the same question.